# Two Excel Questions -- finding string values and saving the excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vbscript

I am making a vbscript that is outputting to an excel spreadsheet.
This will be run on multiple systems on different days, so I want to make the name of the spreadsheet 
*hostname&date*.xls

How can I do a  save as on it, I've been googling but can't find it.

Also, I only have two columns but some text in the second column will be either "Test PASSED" or "Test FAILED". There are about 25 rows. I want to make it so the rows that have "TEST PASSED" in the second column are green and then red vice versa.

How should I go about this?

Comment: I didn't clarify too well, sorry about that. I also need to search each cell in that column to see if it has "PASSED" or "FAILED".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer conditional formatting:

```
  With Table1.Range("$A:$A,$B:$B").FormatConditions.Add( _
        Type:=xlExpression, _
        Formula1:="=AND($B1=""Y"")")

   .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
  End With

  With Table1.Range("$A:$A,$B:$B").FormatConditions.Add( _
        Type:=xlExpression, _
        Formula1:="=AND($B1=""X"")")

   .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
  End With
```

Feel free to replace *Table1* with any other table object.

This will **ADD** new Format conditions **every time** one is executing this code.

To create your filename you can use `Format(Now,"dd/mm/yyyy")` and the code of Omnikrys - or a *FileDialog-Object*.

Here a full example:

`ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Environ$("computername") & "_" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yyyy") & ".xlsx"`

Comment: When I do objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Format(Now,"dd/mm/yy") I get a Type Mismatch

Comment: Environ$ is only a VB variable and not a VBScript...hmmmm

Answer (score 1):

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs *filename*

Cells(1, 1).Font.ColorIndex = 3 
Cells(1, 1).Font.Bold = TRUE
Cells(1, 1).Font.Size = 12
```

etc.

If I remember right red is 3, green is 4. Also, any range object should do for changing style attributes like Font. So Range, Selection, etc will work.

To get the new file name I would go with the below code...

```
Set objSysInfo = CreateObject( "WinNTSystemInfo" )
filename = objSysInfo.ComputerName & "-" & Year(Now) & right("00" & Month(Now), 2) & ".xls"
WScript.Echo Replace(WScript.ScriptFullName, WScript.ScriptName, filename)
```

Comment: I didn't realize it was that easy. I noticed the spreadsheet automatically saved to "My Documents". My code was just objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "test". I would like to put the spreadsheet in the same directory that my script is running from...which will be different directories on different systems. Any tips?

Comment: I added a couple lines of code that will get you your full file path/name for the SaveAs you want to do.